# How do I resolve this filtering challenge in data to DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My data in `code snippet` below refers.

I'm stuck in trying to filter out values inside the list of dictionaries in step2.

```
**Desired goal:**

0      0.00\0.00
1    1.765\n2.035
2      0.00\n0.00
3      1.65\n2.21
```

Where 0.00 values are filtered-out because 'P' the specific key-value is not desired ie. 8.50 in this case. I only want to return values of 6.00 and default any other to 0.00 .

`Updated:`
I've added extra line of data where both key 'P' is missing & has negative value. This is throwing KeyError in both solutions provided. How best to handle the KeyError inside the solutions provided?

```
Step1:

data = [[{'A': 2.25, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.63, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 1.765, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 2.035, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 2.33, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.59, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 1.65, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 2.21, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 10},
[{'A': 2.046, 'G': 8, 'T': 6}, {'A': 2.245, 'G': 2, 'P': -1.5, 'T': 7}]]
```

```
Step2:

df = pd.Series(pd.DataFrame(data).applymap(lambda x:x['C']).astype('str').values.tolist()).str.join("\n")
df
0      2.25\1.63
1    1.765\n2.035
2      2.33\n1.59
3      1.65\n2.21
```

As you can see, **values in rows (0) & (3)** should **read 0.00\n0.00 as desired.**

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches your output. Column `2` is the output:

Input:

```
data = [[{'A': 2.25, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.63, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 1.765, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 2.035, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 2.33, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.59, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 1.65, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 2.21, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 10}]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Code:

```
df[2] = df[0].apply(lambda x: ['0.00\\0.00'  for (a,b) in x.items() if a == 'P' if b == 8.5]).str[0]
df[2] = (df[2].fillna(df[0].apply(lambda x: [f'{b}' for (a,b) in x.items() if a == 'A']).str[0] + '\n' +
         df[1].apply(lambda x: [f'{b}' for (a,b) in x.items() if a == 'A']).str[0]))
df
```

Output:

```
Out[1]: 
                                         0  \
0   {'A': 2.25, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 9}   
1  {'A': 1.765, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 9}   
2   {'A': 2.33, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 9}   
3   {'A': 1.65, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 9}   

                                          1              2  
0   {'A': 1.63, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 10}      0.00\0.00  
1  {'A': 2.035, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 10}   1.765\n2.035  
2   {'A': 1.59, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 10}      0.00\0.00  
3   {'A': 2.21, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 10}     1.65\n2.21
```

---

**Full Explanation and output with more intermediate columns:**

```
data = [[{'A': 2.25, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.63, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 1.765, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 2.035, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 2.33, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.59, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 1.65, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 2.21, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 10}]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#condition of a key-value pair being P and 8.5...
# ...calling x.items() allows you to simultaneously loop through key value pairs 
# ...and return the desired output for the condition while NaN for those that don't meet it
#... we use list comprehension to achieve this and you can use `.str[0]` to transform from list with one value to value
df[2] = df[0].apply(lambda x: ['0.00\\0.00'  for (a,b) in x.items() if a == 'P' if b == 8.5]).str[0]

#... just like above logic is easier but conditionally return values if A for column 1
df[3] = df[0].apply(lambda x: [f'{b}' for (a,b) in x.items() if a == 'A']).str[0]

#... just like above logic is easier but conditionally return values if A for column 2
df[4] = df[1].apply(lambda x: [f'{b}' for (a,b) in x.items() if a == 'A']).str[0]

# fill NaN values for column 3 with combined string of columns 4 and 5
df[5] = df[2].fillna(df[3] + '\n' + df[4])
df
Out[839]: 
                                         0  \
0   {'A': 2.25, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 9}   
1  {'A': 1.765, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 9}   
2   {'A': 2.33, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 9}   
3   {'A': 1.65, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 9}   

                                          1          2      3      4  \
0   {'A': 1.63, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 10}  0.00\0.00   2.25   1.63   
1  {'A': 2.035, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 10}        NaN  1.765  2.035   
2   {'A': 1.59, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 10}  0.00\0.00   2.33   1.59   
3   {'A': 2.21, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 10}        NaN   1.65   2.21   

              5  
0     0.00\0.00  
1  1.765\n2.035  
2     0.00\0.00  
3    1.65\n2.21
```

Comment: The solution is working. Is it possible for you to break down the how/steps for me? Thank you; I'm going to sleep well :)

Comment: Appreciated the solution and explanation as well. Thanks

Comment: I've added extra data that is throwing KeyError when this data is available. I put the info under Update. Not familiar with how this is done but hopefully it's clear enough to follow.

Comment: @stephen.m I would suggest following up with a base SO question if you need a response more quickly. You can reference this question.

Comment: Noted. Will do perhaps in a day or two. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

update with `dict`'s `get` method.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.apply(lambda x: f'''
{x[0]['A'] if x[0].get('P', 0) == 6.00 else '0.00'}
{x[1]['A'] if x[1].get('P', 0) == 6.00 else '0.00'}
'''.strip(), axis=1)
```

---

same solution with different denote:

```py
df.apply(lambda x: [
         str(x[col]['A'])
           if x[col].get('P', 0) == 6.00 
           else '0.00'
         for col in df.columns
], axis=1).str.join('\n')
```

---

```
data = [[{'A': 2.25, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.63, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 1.765, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 2.035, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 2.33, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.59, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.50, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 1.65, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 2.21, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 10}],
[{'A': 2.046, 'G': 8, 'T': 6}, 
 {'A': 2.245, 'G': 2, 'P': -1.5, 'T': 7}]
]

output:
0      0.00\n0.00
1    1.765\n2.035
2      0.00\n0.00
3      1.65\n2.21
4      0.00\n0.00
dtype: object
```

Comment: I was doing a follow through on the solution provided. It works well except I get an error when 'P' isn't available in data. How can I handle that situation within your solution? Thanks

Comment: use dict's `get` method

Comment: Ok..will try that. Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm stuck...where and how do I implement the syntax in the code? I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' if I apply data.get("P", 0)  apologies...learning.

Comment: maybe you can update your question, and post the unexpected situation.

Comment: I've added the extra info under Update. Trust it's clear enough to follow. Thanks

Comment: Great, it's working as intended. Thank you :)